# Function SegFault with Arrays of Structs

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I am using this function:

```
int times_on_table(char *search,struct table index[],int wct){
 int ct=0,num=0;
 while(ct<wct){
     if(strcmp(search,(index[ct].label))==0) {
         num++;
     }
     ct++;
 }
 return num;
}
```

to search through an array of structs and find all the times a certain string is stored in the array and returns the number of times the string occurs. Whenever i use this function inside main:

```
/*EDIT: i had a main from the wrong program my apologies*/

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int numwds=get_num_words(argv[1]);
    struct table index[numwds];

    int a;
    struct cmd_ops symbol[22];
    store(argv[1],index,numwds);
    ops_gen(symbol);
    int b=times_on_table("in",index,numwds);
    printf("%d",b);
}
```

the code works fine. However, when i try to use it inside certain functions like this one

```
struct table* store(char *filename,struct table index[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    char *a;int d=0,e=0,t=0;
    a=malloc(60);
    int wordcount=get_num_words(filename);
    while(d<wordcount){
        fscanf(fp,"%s",a);
        if ((index[d].label=strdup(a))==NULL)
            break;
        index[d].word_num=d;

        times_on_table("this",index,wordcount);/*when i comment this out
                                                 of my code it runs fine*/

        index[d].address=findline(filename,index[d].label,wordcount,index,t);
        d++;
    }
    free(a);
}
```

the code does not run and gives me a segmentation fault. Any thoughts?

EDIT: I don't know if this helps but when i get the segfault, it happens before even the first line of code in main is executed.

EDIT:here is the other function that causes a segfault when times_on_table() is called:

```
int findline(char *filename,char *check,int wordcount,struct table index[],int t){
char *a;
a=malloc(60);
int b=line_count(filename);
int ch;
fpos_t pos;

int line=0,wd=0,loc,s=0,c=1,times;

times=times_on_table(check,index,wordcount);

FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(filename,"r");

int list[wordcount];

while(c<=b){
    fscanf(fp,"%s",a);
    fgetpos(fp,&pos);

    ch=fgetc(fp);ch=fgetc(fp);

    if(strcmp(a,check)==0){
       if(times==0)
            return line;
       else
            times--;
    }

    if(ch==10){
        line++;c++;
    }
    else
        fsetpos(fp,&pos);
    }
    return line;
 }
```

it was in this function that i first added times_on_table(), and had the segmentation fault keep my program from running.

Comment: My thought is that you should run it in a debugger, in order to find the exact line of code that gives the seg-fault.

Comment: You can then inspect the value of the various variables at that point, to determine why it seg-faulted.  You can then work backward to isolate the problem.

Comment: Have you tried valgrind?

Comment: i tried to run it through gdb but it won't run the at all if i don't comment out the use of times_on_table in the store function

Comment: "I don't know if this helps but when i get the segfault, it happens before even the first line of code in main is executed." That's unlikely. How do you determine when the segfault occurs?

Comment: i put a printf statement right at the very beginning of main, and nothing came up when i tried to run it

Comment: @sociospiral Did your `printf`  contain a newline? If not, it's buffering that prevented it from showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
while(d<wordcount){
    fscanf(fp,"%s",a);
    if ((index[d].label=strdup(a))==NULL)
        break;
    index[d].word_num=d;

    times_on_table("this",index,wordcount);
```

you try to count the occurrences of `"this"` in a `wordcount` long array, but you have only filled `d+1` slots of the array. The other slots may contain garbage, and then accessing `index[ct].label` is likely to cause a segmentation fault when `ct > d`.

Comment: the segmentation fault happens before times_on_table() is called, even before store() is called

Comment: How do you know? The only chance for a segfault before calling `store()` is `get_num_words()`. But if that crashes, the crash wouldn't be influenced by the indicated line of code. If you go by the debugging output, the (now removed) `printf("this");` would likely not show up because output is line-buffered.

Comment: if i put up a printf("*"); in main before anything is called or executed, shouldn't there be a * before the segfault? because there isn't

Comment: @sociospiral not without a newline in the printed string.

Comment: and also i'm not talking about the debugging output, i'm talking about the normal output. The only debugging output i get from gdb is: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault._IO_getc (fp=0x0) at getc.c:40

Comment: Debugging or normal output, `stdout` is usually line-buffered, so without having an `\n` in the output strings, you probably won't see anything in case of a segfault. Regarding the gdb info, what is line 40 in `getc.c`?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely you are going past the array index.  These two lines do not really match up (from the code you have shared with us :

```
int wordcount=get_num_words(filename);
times_on_table("this",index,wordcount);
```

(wordcount I assume counts something in `filename` which is passed in as the first parameter, but it seems irrelevant to your `struct table index[]`)

So the parameter being passed in `struct table index[]`, is probably a different size than the value you are storing into `wordcount`.  I would suggest you pass in the array size as a parameter to the `store` function and use that as you would in your working `main` example.  example

```
struct table* store(char *filename,struct table index[], int structSize){
....
times_on_table("this",index,structSize); //replace b from the call in main
}
```

Comment: he is not outside of the array. he is already reaching the array from d to wordcount inside the while loop in the function "store"

Answer (score 0):

It may be related with setting the "index[d].label" properly. Try to print all the labels outside the times_on_table() function without comparing them with anything.

Comment: done, all of the labels print fine outside the times_on_table()